# C# WCF Client Argument Exception XmlNode[] cannot be converted to type "..."

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, soap, client

I'm trying to create a SOAP Client with C# and WCF.

My Environment:

- Visual Studio 2019
- .net Core 3.0 MVC Project
- WSDL Url with Basic Authentification

Code:

```
AccountServicePortClient.EndpointConfiguration configuration = new AccountServicePortClient.EndpointConfiguration();
AccountServicePortClient client = new AccountServicePortClient(configuration);
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXX";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXX";
Task<CheckAddressSuccess> success = client.checkAddressAsync(*Some Arguments*);
success.Wait();
CheckAddressSuccess successResult= success.Result;
```

When receiving the result I get an ArgumentException:

> Object of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' cannot be converted to type 'ServiceReference2.CheckAddressSuccess'

Does anyone have a idea how i could solve this problem?

**Update:**

The Client was created by adding the WSDL URL as WCF Provider. I did not build the Soap Service. I already found out that the SOAP Response CheckAddressSuccess has a typo in the Namespace ("http..." instead of "https..."). I would like to use the WCF DataContractSerializer. How can i accomplish that?

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="https://XXX/account", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference2.AccountServicePort")]
public interface AccountServicePort
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="https://XXX/account#checkAddress", ReplyAction= "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults = true, Use = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="return")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference2.CheckAddressSuccess> checkAddressAsync(string transactionId, ServiceReference2.Address address, bool checkHousenumberAdditive);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="https://XXX/account")]
public partial class CheckAddressSuccess
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem during deserialization. How do you define data contracts? Did you use the XML serializer? In some cases, using XML directly to deserialize custom objects can cause errors. Here is an example.
[https://forums.asp.net/t/1704221.aspx?Unable+to+cast+object+of+type+System+Xml+XmlNode+to+type](https://forums.asp.net/t/1704221.aspx?Unable%20to%20cast%20object%20of%20type%20System%20Xml%20XmlNode%20to%20type)
I would like to know the data contract information of your server and the configuration of creating your server.
Finally, I suggest that you use the DataContractSerializer as the default serializer in WCF.
Please refer to the below serialization advice.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Your advice helped alot. I added an Update in my orginial Post. I would like to use the DataContractSerializer. How can i implement it in my Code?

Comment: In WCF, publishing the service metadata depends on the WCF configuration on the server-side. therefore, modifying the default serializer should be completed on the server-side.